# Change logger level within one same junit5 unit test

Tags: java, logging, junit5, slf4j

*What I would like to achieve:*

I would like to change the logger level within the junit5 unit test.

*Background:*

I have a piece of code I would like to test which looks like this:

```
    public void question(final Foo foo) {
        if (LOGGER.isInfoEnabled() && someConditionVerified(foo)) {
            LOGGER.debug("condition has been verified on Foo");
        }
    }
```

And I would like to change the first condition of the if statement, the log level.
From there, test if the log statement got printed.

*What I have tried:*

In order to do the above, I wrote this:

```
    @Test
    void testLogPrintedBasedOnLogLevel(CapturedOutput output) {
        //set the logger to NOT debug, like maybe info level, the log statment should not be printed
        question(new Foo());
        assertFalse(output.getOut().contains("condition has been verified on Foo"));
        //set the logger to debug so the log can be printed
        question(new Foo());
        assertTrue(output.getOut().contains("condition has been verified on Foo"));
    }
```

*Question:*

I am having a hard time changing the log level within the unit test.

I.e. I am having a hard time with the two commented lines. Could you please help?

Comment: Which Log/logger implementation/version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using slf4j (as tagged) then just try this:

```
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
```

If Using Logback as the Logger Implementation

```
import ch.qos.logback.classic.Level;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger;
```

If Using Log4j 2 as the Logger Implementation

```
import org.apache.log4j.Level;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configurator
```

If Using Java Util Logging

```
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
```

The code below assumes use of Logback (if using log4j 2 then you would use the Configurator to set the Level):

```
Logger testLogger = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger(Logger.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME);
testLogger.setLevel(Level.INFO);
```

or if in a Test Class (i.e. xxx) and different logger then try :

```
Logger xxxLogger = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger(xxx.class);
xxxLogger .setLevel(Level.INFO);
```

Comment: I tried ```import org.slf4j.Logger;``` which does not have the ```setLevel``` method. Which Logger is it?

Comment: Also, I am in a Test Class. Should the statement be as private static final on the class level, or inside the @Test method?

Comment: Apologies will update the answer for the three loggers. ( slf4j is the API that sits on top of your logging framework (i.e. Logback or Log4j 2 or even java.util.logging))

Comment: ```
        org.slf4j.Logger xxxLogger = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoganTransformServiceTest.class);
        xxxLogger.setLevel(org.slf4j.event.Level.INFO);
```

Comment: Apologies, I explicitly added the import class within the code. However, the ```setLevel``` method is still not available.

Comment: Import the actual Logger you are using .  Which Log/logger implementation/version are you using ?